# How to display an image depending on two different input radio button groups without using <form> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to coding. I am taking classes but my teachers aren't really teaching. I have a project where I need to build a webpage where a "customer" can customize their product...a car. I need to use javascript, html, and css. I have never done anything like this before and as I mentioned I am still a newbie. I have had a class on html and css so I know the basics. However, this is my first javascript class....and well...he has just thrown us the project and told us to figure it out. So I am stuck.

Basically this is what I'm trying to accomplish: I need the customer to be able to choose two different options (color, tire type). Based on those options I need the image that is on the page to change once the button is clicked. I know that I do not want to use form tags because I do not want to have to send the "form" off to a server. Or even try to use php. I have 36 different images. There are 6 color choices and 6 tire choices. My images are saved as blackTire1.jpg, blackTire2.jpg, redTire3.jpg, etc. At the moment I'm trying to use switch case to take the values of the checked radio buttons, mash them together, and then use an img src to take that "string" and return the correct picture. I hope that made sense.

What I have is below. I am not worried about css at all right now. My main focus is to just get the code to work first. Bear with me, since i'm still new. This code might have SEVERAL problems and be very messy. If you even see any syntax that or off please mention. Thanks in advance for any input.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function("input:radio[name=color], input:radio[name=tire]") { 
    var colorValue = $('input:radio[name=color]:checked').val(); 
    var tireValue = $('input:radio[name=tire]:checked').val(); 
    var image_name = ""; 
switch (colorValue) {
    case 'black':
        image_name += "black"; 
        break;
    case 'red':
        image_name += "red"; 
        break;
    case 'blue':
        image_name += "blue"; 
        break;
    case 'yellow':
        image_name += "yellow"; 
        break;
    case 'white':
        image_name += "white"; 
        break;  
    case 'silver':
        image_name += "silver";
        break;  
    default:
        image_name += "black"; 
        break;
}

switch (tireValue) {
    case 'Tire1':
        image_name += "Tire1.jpg"; 
        break;
    case 'Tire2':
        image_name += "Tire2.jpg"; 
        break;
    case 'Tire3':
        image_name += "Tire3.jpg"; 
        break;
    case 'Tire4':
        image_name += "Tire4.jpg";
        break;
    case 'Tire5':
        image_name += "Tire5.jpg"; 
        break;  
    case 'Tire6':
        image_name += "Tire6.jpg"; 
        break;  
    default:
        image_name += "Tire1.jpg"; 
        break;
}
alert(image_name);
$image.attr('src', image_name); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<section>
  <img src="blackTire1.jpg" name="formula" id="formula">
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="black" checked /> <img src="black.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red"/> <img src="red.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="silver"/> <img src="silver.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="white"/> <img src="white.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow"/> <img src="yellow.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"/> <img src ="blue.jpg"/>
  <br><br>

  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire1" checked /> <img src="Tire1.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire2"/> <img src="Tire2.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire3"/> <img src="Tire3.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire4"/> <img src="Tire4.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire5"/> <img src="Tire5.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire6"/> <img src="Tire6.jpg"/>
  <br><br>

  <button onclick="function("input:radio[name=color], input:radio[name=tire])">See Your Car</button>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to the code on github: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71dd2a1ed5b39b8486ab1b1117abd4b3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming from the definition of your function.

`function("input:radio[name=color], input:radio[name=rim]") {`

should be

`function changeTireImage() {`

AND the button should be

`<button onclick="changeTireImage();">See Your Car</button>`

AND there was some extra ending code after the function `);`

**EDIT : AND the `$image` variable wasn't defined**

```js
function changeTireImage() { 
    var colorValue = $('input:radio[name=color]:checked').val(); 
    var tireValue = $('input:radio[name=tire]:checked').val(); 
    var image_name = ""; 
    switch (colorValue) {
    case 'black':
        image_name += "black"; 
        break;
    case 'red':
        image_name += "red"; 
        break;
    case 'blue':
        image_name += "blue"; 
        break;
    case 'yellow':
        image_name += "yellow"; 
        break;
    case 'white':
        image_name += "white"; 
        break;  
    case 'silver':
        image_name += "silver";
        break;  
    default:
        image_name += "black"; 
        break;
    }

    switch (tireValue) {
    case 'Tire1':
        image_name += "Tire1.jpg"; 
        break;
    case 'Tire2':
        image_name += "Tire2.jpg"; 
        break;
    case 'Tire3':
        image_name += "Tire3.jpg"; 
        break;
    case 'Tire4':
        image_name += "Tire4.jpg";
        break;
    case 'Tire5':
        image_name += "Tire5.jpg"; 
        break;  
    case 'Tire6':
        image_name += "Tire6.jpg"; 
        break;  
    default:
        image_name += "Tire1.jpg"; 
        break;
    }
    alert(image_name);
    var $image = $('#formula');
    $image.attr('src', image_name); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <img src="blackTire1.jpg" name="formula" id="formula">
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="black" checked /> <img src="black.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red"/> <img src="red.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="silver"/> <img src="silver.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="white"/> <img src="white.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow"/> <img src="yellow.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"/> <img src ="blue.jpg"/>
  <br><br>

  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire1" checked /> <img src="Tire1.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire2"/> <img src="Tire2.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire3"/> <img src="Tire3.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire4"/> <img src="Tire4.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire5"/> <img src="Tire5.jpg"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tire" value="Tire6"/> <img src="Tire6.jpg"/>
  <br><br>

  <button onclick="changeTireImage();">See Your Car</button>

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That was definitely helpful. It is at least doing something now. I still can't get the image to change. This pops up at the top: "This page says: redTire3.jpg" How can I get the image to actually change?

Comment: I didn't see that the `$image` variable wasn't defined. Here it is.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I realized about the image not being defined from apieceofbart who commented earlier. And I put yours and theirs together and it works now. I really appreciate you taking the time. I have been racking my brain for weeks, researching, troubleshooting, etc to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues. First of all you need to give your function a name if you want to call it from html. Something like:

```
<button onclick="setImage('input:radio[name=color]', 'input:radio[name=tire]');">
See Your Car</button>
```

Then in your function you need to pass those parameters:

```
function setImage(colorSelector, tireSelector) { 
    var colorValue = $(colorSelector+':checked').val();
    var tireValue = $(tireSelector+':checked').val();
```

Final thing is you need handler to your image, `$image` is not defined. Instead of `$image.attr('src', image_name);` you need something like
`$('#formula').attr('src', image_name);`

Comment: Thank you, defining the image really helped